# Minecraft server query

Tags: php, sockets

Hello im using this PHP script

https://github.com/FunnyItsElmo/PHP-Minecraft-Server-Status-Query

I'm trying to get the names of all the players to show aswell..

On row 65 in the status.class.php i added this `print_r($data->players);`

And then i get an array with 12 slots or something..

Like this: `stdClass Object ( [max] => 35 [online] => 21 [sample] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [name] => MinecraftNickname ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [5] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [6] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [7] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 8 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [8] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 9 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [9] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 10 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [10] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 11 [name] => MinecraftNickname) [11] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [name] => MinecraftNickname) ) )`

My question is this:

Even if there is 20 players online at the server this $data->players only shows 12, how can i change this so it shows all the nicknames online at the server?

Answer (score 0):

The Query can only display whatever the server answers, that is the server only sends 12 players. If you're using Spigot (or it's derivative), you can edit this number in spigot.yml file under settings.sample-count.

See [Spigot Wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-configuration/#main-ungrouped-settings) for more information.